# How to add a payment option for a specific country?

Tags: store, wallet

I am from Nigeria, I would like to know how to add my debit card and billing information on my `ewallet` in Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in some countries like *Nigeria* and *Brazil* you can't add you `debit card` as a payment option to buy apps on the **Store**.

Alternatively you can change the `country/region` in `settings` and use a prepaid credit card from that region.

I'm currently using my phone in the **USA** region and use an *American Express* prepaid credit card to purchase apps.

Another alternative is you buy *gift cards* from **Microsoft** but is unlikely it will work in all countries too (Here in Brazil this became an option just in January 2014)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not all countries are supported in the Wallet.

I couldn't find a list of the supported countries, but I know for a fact that my home country (Saudi Arabia) is not supported when I tried to add my local credit card. But adding a US credit card worked fine.

Comment: Are you able to expand upon this answer, e.g. provide a source of available countries?

Comment: Is your account set to Arabia or USA? It was a deal breaker in Windows Phone 7.5. Looks like know you just need change the region and you can add payment option for any country.